# How to write the similar code in PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How to write a similar code in Laravel. Below normal PHP code is working fine.

```
<?php 
    foreach ($snippets as $post) {
        $userdata = App\Models\Constant_model::getDataOneColumn('users', 'id', $post->listed_by)->get();
        $userpicture = $userdata[0]->email;
?>
<?php echo $userpicture; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

But I want to change it like this in Laravel.

```
@foreach ($snippets as $post)
    $userdata = App\Models\Constant_model::getDataOneColumn('users', 'id', $post->listed_by)->get();
    $userpicture = $userdata[0]->email;
    {{$userpicture}}
@endforeach
```

The result I am getting is

```
$userdata = App\Models\Constant_model::getDataOneColumn('users', 'id', $post->listed_by)->get();
$userpicture = $userdata[0]->email;
```

Comment: It is better to write the code `@php * Code * @endphp` in `Controller` rather than in a `blade` template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use blade template, you cannot simply mix with a PHP code. Because, blade template is actually a HTML codes. The blade directive (@foreach, {{ }} etc) is actually a short hand for PHP code.

My suggestion is to handle the fetch data from the Controller, and View should be only for displaying the data. But if you insist, you could use the @php directive.

```
@foreach($snippets as $post)

    @php
       $userdata = App\Models\Constant_model::getDataOneColumn('users','id', $post->listed_by)->get();
       $userpicture = $userdata[0]->email;
    @endphp

    {{$userpicture}}


@endforeach
```